# Protractor Debugger cannot find module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, javascript-debugger

I am running my test using protractor with async/await, and trying to use debugger. Entering in promt `node --inspect-brk bin/protractor conf.js`
Than open "chrome://inspect/#devices" in Chrome ("bin/protractor file:/// inspect" shows up), clicking "Inspect" and getting following error in promt:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/85c1f4a4-3048-4c73-b42f-61a5f078ba7e
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\harmatii\Protractor\calbar\bin\protractor'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem in the path for the `protractor` and `conf.js`.
Try to provide the correct path to the `protractor` and `conf.js`.

Should be something like this:

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor /users/harmatii/Protractor/conf.js
```

Comment: tried to specify path `node --inspect-brk users\harmatii\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor \Protractor\calbar\conf.js` but getting same error message: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module VM65 loader.js:636 
C:\Users\harmatii\users\harmatii\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor'`

Comment: almost there, as I can see you provided the path to the `protractor` directory instead of the `protractor` runner. It could be there `C:\Users\harmatii\users\harmatii\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor` or just without `node_modules` `C:\Users\harmatii\users\harmatii\AppData\Roaming\npm\protractor\bin\protractor`

Comment: this worked, thank you node --inspect-brk AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\bin\protractor Protractor\calbar\conf.js